# Getting different accuracies using different caffe classes(98.65 vs 98.1 vs 98.20)

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

When I train and then test my model using Caffe's command line interface, I get e.g. `98.65%` whereas when I myself write code(given below) to calculate accuracy from the same pre-trained model, I get e.g `98.1%` using `Caffe.Net`.
Everything is straight forward and I have no idea what is causing the issue.
I also tried using `Caffe.Classifier` and its `predict` method, and yet get another lesser accuracy(i.e. `98.20%`!)
Here is the snippet of code I wrote:

```python
import sys
import caffe
import numpy as np
import lmdb
import argparse
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import random


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--proto', help='path to the network prototxt file(deploy)', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--model', help='path to your caffemodel file', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--mean', help='path to the mean file(.binaryproto)', type=str, required=True)
    #group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--db_type', help='lmdb or leveldb', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--db_path', help='path to your lmdb/leveldb dataset', type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    predicted_lables=[]
    true_labels = []
    misclassified =[]
    class_names = ['unsafe','safe']
    count=0
    correct = 0
    batch=[]
    plabe_ls=[]
    batch_size = 50
    cropx = 224
    cropy = 224
    i = 0
    multi_crop = False
    use_caffe_classifier = True

    caffe.set_mode_gpu() 
    # Extract mean from the mean image file
    mean_blobproto_new = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.BlobProto()
    f = open(args.mean, 'rb')
    mean_blobproto_new.ParseFromString(f.read())
    mean_image = caffe.io.blobproto_to_array(mean_blobproto_new)
    f.close()

    net = caffe.Classifier(args.proto, args.model,
                           mean = mean_image[0].mean(1).mean(1),
                           image_dims = (224, 224))

    net1 = caffe.Net(args.proto, args.model, caffe.TEST) 
    net1.blobs['data'].reshape(batch_size, 3,224, 224)
    data_blob_shape = net1.blobs['data'].data.shape

    #check and see if its lmdb or leveldb
    if(args.db_type.lower() == 'lmdb'):
        lmdb_env = lmdb.open(args.db_path)
        lmdb_txn = lmdb_env.begin()
        lmdb_cursor = lmdb_txn.cursor()
        for key, value in lmdb_cursor:
            count += 1 
            datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
            datum.ParseFromString(value)
            label = int(datum.label)
            image = caffe.io.datum_to_array(datum).astype(np.float32)
            #key,image,label
            #buffer n image
            if(count % 5000 == 0):          
                print('{0} samples processed so far'.format(count))

            if(i < batch_size):
                i+=1
                inf= key,image,label
                batch.append(inf)
                #print(key)                 
            if(i >= batch_size):
                #process n image 
                ims=[]              
                for x in range(len(batch)):
                    img = batch[x][1]
                    #img has c,w,h shape! its already gone through transpose and channel swap when it was being saved into lmdb!
                    #Method III : use center crop just like caffe does in test time
                    if (use_caffe_classifier != True):
                        #center crop
                        c,w,h = img.shape
                        startx = h//2 - cropx//2
                        starty = w//2 - cropy//2
                        img = img[:, startx:startx + cropx, starty:starty + cropy]                  
                        #transpose the image so we can subtract from mean 
                        img = img.transpose(2,1,0)
                        img -= mean_image[0].mean(1).mean(1)
                        #transpose back to the original state
                        img = img.transpose(2,1,0)
                        ims.append(img)
                    else:
                        ims.append(img.transpose(2,1,0))    

                if (use_caffe_classifier != True): 
                    net1.blobs['data'].data[...] = ims[:]
                    out_1 = net1.forward()
                    plabe_ls = out_1['pred']                                                                                 
                else:
                    out_1 = net.predict(np.asarray(ims), oversample=multi_crop)
                    plabe_ls = out_1    

                plbl = np.asarray(plabe_ls)
                plbl = plbl.argmax(axis=1)
                for j in range(len(batch)):
                    if (plbl[j] == batch[j][2]):
                        correct+=1
                    else:
                        misclassified.append(batch[j][0])

                    predicted_lables.append(plbl[j])        
                    true_labels.append(batch[j][2]) 
                batch.clear()
                i = 0               


    sys.stdout.write("\rAccuracy: %.2f%%" % (100.*correct/count))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print(", %i/%i corrects" % (correct, count))
```

What is causing this difference in accuracies ?

**More information :**
I am using Python3.5 on windows.
I read images from an `lmdb` dataset.
The images have `256x256` and center cropped with the size `224x224`.
It is finetuned on `GoogleNet`.
For the `Caffe.predict` to work well I had to change `classify.py`
In training, I just use `Caffes` defaults, such as random crops at training and center crop at test-time.

**Changes:**
changed line 35 to:

```
 self.transformer.set_transpose(in_, (2, 1, 0))
```

and line 99 to :

```
predictions = predictions.reshape((len(predictions) // 10, 10, -1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First off, you need to revert Line 35 (32?) of `classify.py`: `self.transformer.set_transpose(in_, (2, 1, 0))` back to the original
`self.transformer.set_transpose(in_, (2, 0, 1))`. So it expects HWC and transforms internally to CHW for downstream processing.

2) Run your Classifier branch as it is. You're likely to get a bad result. Please check this. If so, it means the image database is not CWH as you've commented, but actually CHW. After you've confirmed this, make the change to your Classifier branch: `ims.append(img.transpose(2,1,0))` to become `ims.append(img.transpose(1,2,0))`. Re-test your Classifier branch. The result should be `98.2%` (goto Step 3) or `98.65%` (try Step 4).

3) If your result in Step 3 is `98.2%`, also undo your the second change to `classify.py`. Theoretically, as your images have even height/width so `//` and `/` should have no difference. If it does differ or crashes, something is seriously wrong with your image database -- your assumption of the image size is incorrect. You need to check these. They could be off by a pixel or so, and could explain the slight discrepancies in accuracy.

4) If your result in Step 3 is `98.65%`, then you need to make changes to the `Caffe.Net` branch of your code. The database images are CHW, so you need to make the first transpose: `img = img.transpose(1,2,0)` and the second transpose after mean subtraction to `img = img.transpose(2,0,1)`. Then run your `Caffe.Net` branch. If you still get `98.1%` as before, you should check that mean subtraction is performed correctly by your network.

In Steps (2) and (4), it's possible to get worse results, which means that the problem is likely a difference in mean subtraction for your trained Net vs your expectations in Python code. Check this.

About your `98.2%` for the `caffe.Classifier`:

If you look at  [lines 78 - 80](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/classifier.py), the center crop is done along `crop_dims` , not `img_dims`. If you further look at line 42 on the `caffe.Classifier` constructor, the `crop_dims` are never user-determined. It's determined by the size of the Net's input blobs. Lastly, it you look at line 70, the `img_dims` are used to *resize* the images prior to center cropping. So what's happening with your setup is: a) The images are first getting *resized* to 224 x 224, then uselessly getting center cropped to 224 x 224 ( I assume this is the HxW for your Net ). You obviously will get results poorer than `98.65%`. What you need to do is to change the `img_dims = (256, 256)`. That prevents resizing. The crop will be picked up automatically from your Net and you should get your `98.65%`.

Comment: The test accuracy must not change for an existing pre-trained model. 
Yes if I was to train and then test each time, getting different accuracies is understandable, but using only one pre-trained model, with the exact same data-augmentation should always give the same accuracy.

Comment: Correct. However you mentioned "when I train and test my models" in your original question. So to clarify, you're observing discrepancies in accuracy for the exact same pretrained model during the test phase only?

Comment: Yes, thats right, maybe I conveyed myself badly in the question.  
the issue is that at test time, I get different accuracies, although close, but different to each other. the highest accuracy is attainable through caffe test itself which uses center crops + mean subtraction. yet when I do it myself as you can see using the code snippet above, I fail to get the same exact accuracy.

Comment: first of all caffe classifier used preprocess method, which requires input to be in the form of HWC, thats why I' transposing it. 
apart from that, either cases cant provide the accuracy which I get using caffe test!

Comment: I meant internally, both the classifier and net use CHW. You edited the `classify.py` so that the transformer internally transforms HWC input into CWH. Why do this? Did you train your net on CWH internally rather than the standard CHW?

Comment: first of all I was reading from an lmdb created by caffe's convert_imageset.exe and thus image dimensions were transposed into the form of `cwh`. whereas `transfoermer.preprocess` wants the input to have the shape `h,w,c` .that's why I am doing a transpose. If I don't do that, the resize method called from preprocess would take 0.6 seconds for each image! which is very inefficient.  
Both of classifier and net require you to feed them with inputs of shape hwc and then they internally transpose. 
if I dont change the dimension in `classify.py`, the accuracy would be extremely bad!

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can just transpose in your Python code without fiddling with classify.py. Did you use the same lmdb when you evaluated the net using caffe comandiine?

Comment: I thought so as well, but thats what I ended up doing.
you can go ahead and test it for yourself. you should be able to easily replicate this. I'm using python35, windows branch, using googlenet, on a dataset created using caffe's convert_imageset and see this first hand. 
Yes, I did the same lmdb

Comment: I suspect the problem lies in how mean subtraction is done. This could lead to the slight differences you're seeing. I've edit my answer based on this, perhaps something you could try.

Comment: Thank you very much, your points make sense, I'll give them a try and report back when I'm done

Comment: you were 100% right. Thank you very much. 
in part 3 I got 98.20% (Caffe classifier) and for the Caffe.Net(part 4) I could get the same exact accuracy 98.65%. 
How ever why Cant I get the same exact accuracy in caffe classifier?

Comment: You've fed `image_dims = (224, 224)` into `caffe.Classifier`. Are you sure this means a center crop?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the Classify.py line 83, it reads :
` # Take center crop.` in the else clause (when oversample is False)

Comment: Yes, but does it center crop along the `img_dims` dimensions you've put in?   I've edited my answer yet again to answer in full.

Comment: Oh, I see, yes you are right :) Thank you very much indeed :)